# Can't Update a Document library

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

Using the MS Graph SDK for .NET CORE, Creating a document library works fine.
The new Library has the "Allow management of content types?" as yes
But I can't change the content types and the Display name.

On the code below, the library is created but I can do update to anything.
the last line errors with :
Code: -1, Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.InvalidClientQueryException
Message: Invalid request.
Inner error:
        AdditionalData:
        request-id: 8e38aeac-39fb-4e59-b3eb-2280a353753a
        date: 10/21/2019 9:21:09 PM
ClientRequestId: 8e38aeac-39fb-4e59-b3eb-2280a353753a

```
List list = new List
             {
              ListInfo = rootList.ListInfo,
               DisplayName = rootList.Name,
               Description = rootList.Description,
              };
List newList = await graphClient.Groups[project.GroupID].Sites["root"].Lists.Request().AddAsync(list); // This line works
     _log.LogInformation("newList.Id = " + newList.Id); //Gets a new Guid
      List uplist = new List
       {
        Description = "Bla bla" //Or anything
        };
List updList = await graphClient.Groups[project.GroupID].Sites["root"].Lists[newList.Id].Request().UpdateAsync(uplist); // This line Fails
```

I did not find any good documentation for applying content types to a List or Library. 
The "UpdateAsync(uplist)" hinted it does a "Patch" so I used it.

Is there a better way to apply content types.
I tried with Drive but it does not have a ContentTypes property.
Thanks for any hint.

Answer (score 1):

If you look closely at the MS Graph documentation, you will notice that updating a **list** is not supported -- only updating **list items**.

You will likely need to use the legacy SharePoint API (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/working-with-lists-and-list-items-with-rest?redirectedfrom=MSDN#working-with-lists-by-using-rest) or a Site Script (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/site-design-json-schema#addcontenttype)

Comment: Thank you Paul.   Your links are great.  I just have issues getting an accessToken with .NET Core 2.2.    I am using "RESTSharp" and it has something about auth2.0 But I could not make it work with My clientID and client secret (from SharePoint, not Azure like for Graph)  Would you know a resource that will help me do it?   any hint may help :-) Thanks again

Comment: I don't know what RESTSharp is. However, you can use a token from AAD for SharePoint. Just use the SharePoint domain as the scope.

There is an example in the Graph.Community library: https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet-contrib/blob/master/samples/ChangeLog.cs