# use the "GraphServiceClient" to send REST calls to SharePoint online

Tags: azure-functions, microsoft-graph-sdks

In an Azure function build with Core 2.2 and Microsoft.Graph 1.18.0, I am able to use "GraphServiceClient" to do: 
- create a 365 group that also creates a team site.
- Copy site columns and content types to it
- create new document libraries

But then I can't assign a content type to a library.
The "GraphServiceClient" authenticates with app id and client secret.
So I want to use RESTSharp Core to send REST posts to assign a content type to a library. But I can't find a way to authenticates with the same app id and client secret.
I am assuming the "GraphServiceClient" has a Token somewhere that I can use with rest calls but I can figure out where it is.

```
            string GraphClientId = GetEnvironmentVariable("GraphClientId");
            string GraphTenantId = GetEnvironmentVariable("GraphTenantId");
            string GraphClientSecret = GetEnvironmentVariable("GraphClientSecret");
            IConfidentialClientApplication confidentialClientApplication = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
                       .Create(GraphClientId)
                       .WithTenantId(GraphTenantId)
                       .WithClientSecret(GraphClientSecret)
                       .Build();
            ClientCredentialProvider authProvider = new ClientCredentialProvider(confidentialClientApplication);
            graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(authProvider);
```

the token is somewhere in graphClient.{Where?}

Since there are some things you can't do with Graph,
Is there a way to use the "GraphServiceClient" that is already authenticated, to send REST calls to SharePoint online of the same tenant?

Comment: What is it you're unable to do with the Graph SDK that you expect RESTSharp to be able to accomplish? The SDK is built off the Graph API metadata so there are _very_ few scenarios the SDK cannot handle. In most cases, if the SDK can't do it then it is because the Graph API itself doesn't support it.

Comment: See @Paul answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58494552/cant-update-a-document-library/58509062#58509062)   I am trying to assign a content type to new Library.

Comment: The token used by the SDK won't do you any good since its bound to Microsoft Graph. You'll need to generate a separate token for SharePoint to use the SharePoint APIs.

Comment: Thanks, I gave up and went back to Ugly CSOM on net 461 :-)